# Magento Intraship PDF Creation Failed

Tags: php, mysql, magento, dhl

I am using the DHL Intraship Module to handle shipping and create shipping labels.

Most of the time I can print the labels without any problems, but from time to time I receive the following error message:

```
pdf creation failed. service temporary not available. Unable to save PDF to [...] /var/intraship/documents/pdf--a/pdf--a2/pdf--a29/label-00340433836395078284.pdf.
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out, what causes the error. It's independet from the items ordered, adress, amount, type of shipment or payment or any other variable I could imagine.

The problem is, that it only happens with some of the orders - let's say I can print 20 labels in a row and the next 3 ones do not work. Due to the fact that it's not related to the time and I can print a lot of labeld in once and then just two not, I don't think it is related to an overload of the server's working memory.

Furthermore, I checked that
 - Directory permission are correct (777)
 - url_fopen is set to allwo
 - there is no file (label) with the same name: The file is created, but has 0byte.

Still, the shipemnt is initiatet at DHL and brought to account.

The Intraship module by nr-apps is pretty common and widely used in germany and I don't think that there are any specific error with the extension. I also had contact with the developers, but I checked everything they could imagine (see points mentioned above).

Does anybody has an idea what else could cause the error?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. 0 byte PDF, the error message in the order comments and the mysterious error text "FPDF error: Unable to find pointer to xref table".

After searching through the code of the extension I found the place where the error is created (`app/code/community/Dhl/Intraship/Helper/Pdf.php` on line 143):

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    throw new Dhl_Intraship_Helper_Pdf_Exception(
        'pdf creation failed. service temporary not available. ' . $e->getMessage(),
        $e->getCode()
    );
}
```

As the error was logged, I searched through the error log in `var/log/system.log` and found the related exception message:

```
2015-04-16T17:52:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): Unable to save PDF to /path-to-your-app/var/intraship/documents/pdf--X/pdf--XX/pdf--XXX/label-<code>.pdf.
2015-04-16T17:52:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.intraship.de:80/cartridge/WSPrint?code=<long code>): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    in /path-to-your-app/app/code/community/Dhl/Intraship/Helper/Pdf.php on line 143
```

So for me the error is the (recently pretty unstable) DHL Intraship API. This doesn't mean that you receive the same error or that the error cause is the same, but at least you have an indicator where to look for the error messages that might help you with the solution.

For me the only remaining option is to contact the DHL Intraship support about the HTTP 500 errors.